# JPA custom findOne and findAll

Tags: jpa, customization, spring-data, findall

I have a table place that contain as column "state" (it is an Enum that can be 'ACTIVE' or 'INACTIVE')

I would like to know if there is a way with JPA2 that when i call placeRepository.findAll() or placeRepository.getOne(id) only select the row in the database that are marked as "ACTIVE" ?

something like this

```
List<Place> findByStateActiveOnly();
```

**EDIT:**
Bonus question:
I'am at the moment refactoring my project to be able to add a place (and other entities) in a pending state. Because I have added an extra column "state" now i have to add to ALL my queries this condition  `"AND p.state=my.package.State.ACTIVE"` like this;

```
@Query("select p from Place p where p.idPlace = ?1 AND p.state=my.package.State.ACTIVE")
```

Isn't there a way to tell jpa to automatically select me if the state is ACTIVE ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?

Comment: Yes I do use Hibernate

Comment: `placeRepository.findAll()` is your implementation, or somthing like spring-data repository?

Comment: it is a method of org.springframework.data.repository.CrudeRepository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Hibernate, you can try annotating your entity with [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html), something like this

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "state = 'ACTIVE'")
public class Place {...}
```

Comment: I didn't know we could do such a thing. But this make me ask an other question (see the edit in my first question). At the moment every single query in my project looks like something like this
@Query("select p from Place p where p.idPlace = ?1 AND p.state=my.package.State.ACTIVE"). Will using you answer avoid to every time adding this "add condition" ?

Comment: @Johny19 Yes, it will be added by Hibernate to every query. I didn't try it in combination with spring-data repositories, but I don't see any reason it shoudn't work.

Comment: I just tried, and it works like a charm! No need to modify all my queries now :O

Comment: Sorry to reopen the question. But if my Entity has a "@ManyToOne" relation how can also force this relation to ONLY return row that contains ACTIVE ?

Comment: I think if you just move the annotation from enity level to `@ManyToOne` level, it will be applied only to that specific relation

Comment: @Johny19 Did you try it, does it work when you map the relation instead of class?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with where. I Have tried with Filter and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do with parameter:

```
public interface YourRepository ... {
    List<Place> findByState(String state);
}
```

you will invoke like:

```
List<Place> placeList = youRepository.findByState("ACTIVE");
```

Comment: Yes this is one way to do it. But i was interested to know if there was a way without parameter.